# Too many edits—how can I contact a moderator?

Tags: support, edits, post-ban, rate-limiting

I've been banned from asking questions. I have to ask some necessary questions urgently.

I found that the only way to remove the question ban is to improve the question quality.

So, I edited my old questions.

After I edited some posts I got a message:

> Too many edits
> You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow.
> Please contact a moderator if you require assistance.

So, how can I contact a moderator?

Comment: After editing five posts, you should maybe step back anyway and wait to see if the edits do make the posts more acceptable. The reactions to those edits may affect your future editing.

Comment: Your recent edits are all **`like this`**, i.e., adding emphasis around **entire questions** and `putting code ticks around everything slightly related to computers`, while you ignore obvious grammar, spelling, punctuation, and style errors; not only on your own posts, but also on others'. Please stop doing that.

Comment: I just want to enhance the readability.I will care other things also , now onwards

Comment: Using code blocks for anything that isn't code doesn't enhance readability. If anything, you are making things worse.

Comment: Using boldface doesn't enhance readability either. It's just shouting. Boldface is for posters. Use italics if you must, *sparingly.*

Comment: This is the system's way of saying `step back from the computer for a moment and do something else`.

Comment: Also [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 5-edits-a-day limit is put in place to prevent users from vandalizing their own posts. Unfortunately, we cannot lift this once it has been enforced, much like how we cannot lift a question ban. Even if you flag one of your posts for moderator attention, we cannot do anything to help you.

Besides, even if you edit all your questions, the results aren't going to be immediate. If you're always asking urgent questions, our only advice is to stop doing that, because urgent questions tend to be the worst kind of questions that we receive by far. If you continue this practice you will simply find yourself getting banned and having to edit your previous — possibly also urgent — questions after the fact repeatedly, which just wastes your own time more than anybody else's. If you put more time and effort into your questions from the get-go, they will surely be better-received.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question "how can I contact moderator"

Comment: @Cherona You are not supposed to contact a moderator. As the answer says: *"Even if you flag one of your posts for moderator attention, we cannot do anything to help you."*

Comment: @CodyGray Why does the "Too many edits" error page say "Please contact a moderator if you require assistance."? Is it referring to assistance with the error?

Comment: @Cherona Yes, I assume that's what it is. I'm really not sure. It may be a bug, requiring that the error message updated. There is almost certainly no reason to contact a moderator when exceeding a rate limit. There's nothing moderators can do about it, either.