# How do I apply a license to the code in dozens of my old posts?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, rate-limiting, mit-license

Only today did I learn about the [use of the MIT License for new code going forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/229356). I wanted to relicense non-trivial code in my old answers to be consistent with the terms for code in new answers. But now I've run into this problem:

> Too many edits
>
> You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow.
>
> Please contact a moderator if you require assistance.

I understand the rationale behind this throttle: to keep users from [spamming "active" with bumps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290345/does-editing-a-old-post-bring-it-up-to-the-front) and to [limit a user's ability to vandalize his posts when rage-quitting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280285/2738262). But was it also the intent to make it take days or weeks to expand the terms under which a user's original code is offered for use by the public?

I wanted to apply the notice to each answer in order to make it clear which answers contain my original code and which contain mostly code copied or derived from the question (CC BY-SA), another answer (CC BY-SA), or an external resource. I considered [specifying a dual license in my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291319/is-it-valid-if-one-licenses-their-own-answer-at-stack-overflow), but then I'd still need to edit each answer to state whether my code is original and thus is eligible for the license specified in my profile.

Is there a better way to go about specifying to which posts a relicense applies? Or should I just list the relicense-eligible posts in my profile until I complete editing the license notice into each individual post?

---

Low level details follow:

The text that I had planned to append is as follows:

```
<sub>Code in this answer is dual licensed: [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) or the [MIT License as published by OSI](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).</sub>
```

The edit summary that I had planned to use is as follows:

```
Dual license old code to match [terms for new code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/229356)
```

The affected answers are as follows:

- [Bit-wise operations to implement logical shift to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964802/bit-wise-operations-to-implement-logical-shift-to-the-right/25964860#25964860)
- [How do I implement the Pratt gap sequence? (Python, Shell Sort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964453/how-do-i-implement-the-pratt-gap-sequence-python-shell-sort/25964763#25964763)
- [Something like debugDumpParams in pdo settable to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157331/something-like-debugdumpparams-in-pdo-settable-to-a-string/25315378#25315378)
- [Replacing a text node by another in xml using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626455/replacing-a-text-node-by-another-in-xml-using-python/18626647#18626647)
- [Read Contents Tarfile into Python - "seeking backwards is not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623842/read-contents-tarfile-into-python-seeking-backwards-is-not-allowed/18624269#18624269)
- [Turning a flat Python tuple into a nested dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624292/turning-a-flat-python-tuple-into-a-nested-dictionary/18624330#18624330)
- [MySQL, MySQLi, MySQL Prepared Statement or PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984482/mysql-mysqli-mysql-prepared-statement-or-pdo/27407622#27407622)
- [Make object return float value python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326729/make-object-return-float-value-python/27326828#27326828)
- [In place edit update text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280071/in-place-edit-update-text/27280192#27280192)
- [Sorting characters in a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641131/sorting-characters-in-a-file-in-c/26641509#26641509)
- [Python Function: Given Scrabble Tile, What is the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636868/python-function-given-scrabble-tile-what-is-the-value/26637177#26637177)
- [What does str[newLength] = '\0' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558741/what-does-strnewlength-0-mean/26558831#26558831)
- [Checking if a text contains words from a txt file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629576/checking-if-a-text-contains-words-from-a-txt-file-in-php/27630080#27630080)
- [Convert image to specific palette using PIL without dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433243/convert-image-to-specific-palette-using-pil-without-dithering/29438149#29438149)
- [Is there a way to update certain objects 'live' on a webpage with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728155/is-there-a-way-to-update-certain-objects-live-on-a-webpage-with-python-3/28728641#28728641)
- [Working around 1 MB max_allowed_packet when reading MEDIUMBLOB in PDO MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753499/working-around-1-mb-max-allowed-packet-when-reading-mediumblob-in-pdo-mysql/29753500#29753500)
- [python list to dict conversion confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167228/python-list-to-dict-conversion-confusion/31167704#31167704)
- [Python csv writer: write a string in front of an array, all in individual columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898584/python-csv-writer-write-a-string-in-front-of-an-array-all-in-individual-column/30898747#30898747)
- [SELECT in CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879472/select-in-concat/30879988#30879988)
- [Check key existence in nested dictionnaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677325/check-key-existence-in-nested-dictionnaries/30677855#30677855)

Comment: Let's not do license-related mass edits until the details are hashed out in a couple weeks

Comment: @Pekka웃 So how did this thread ended?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I don't know what the latest dvelopment is, I lost track....

Answer (score 1):

It seems the MIT license doesn't apply to old answers, and that [they're considering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-on-the-stack-excha) ways to opt them in to that scheme that wouldn't need mass editing - "Code that was contributed prior to January 1, 2016 will be available for use as it has always been, under the terms of CC-BY-SA. We are looking into ways we might allow users to opt-in old code contributions to the new scheme."

Maybe leave off editing and see if they roll out a way to add it automatically? Alternatively, 5 edits a day will get your changes made long before this comes into effect.