# Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?

Tags: support, faq, asking-questions

We often have people desiring speedy answers to a question, and they will add phrases intended to elicit solutions quickly. For example:

- This is urgent for me
- Please reply ASAP!
- I am under a tight deadline [of <date>]
- I've been stuck for hours/days/weeks
- My educator/manager is angry/upset because of my [potentially] late delivery
- I am desperate / I am tearing my hair out
- Eagerly waiting for your reply / I am waiting online

I wondered whether the community believes the addition of these phrases might help prioritise which questions are more important than others, and under which circumstances, if any, it is acceptable.

It occurs to me that, for example, the community may wish to discourage a user from using these phrases liberally, since it is unfair to ask for urgent help in cases when a task is not subject to a deadline on this occasion. Equally, we may take the view that since we have no way of determining if a poster has a need for urgency, we would prefer it if all posters would refrain from these sorts of additions.

The community may wish to take a view on the possibility that these phrases may accidentally constitute an expectation upon readers, and that in some English-speaking cultures, this attitude towards volunteers might be understood as demanding or rude.

I expect some people will hold the view that the addition of these phrases actually makes no difference in hurrying answers, and that in some cases it may attract downvotes (either because the voter sees a lack of succinctness, or they feel it is inappropriate to rush volunteers).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/)

---

**Canonical link:** `[Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)`

Comment: What happened to the answers to this question? So many highly-upvoted but deleted posts!

Comment: @KevinWorkman: unfortunately they were axed in a tidy-up. I think that is policy when a Meta post is added to the FAQ. Personally I thought they added colour and context, but I wasn't particularly minded to see if it could be reversed.

Comment: @KevinWorkman: I just spotted that a few answers were recently undeleted.

Comment: “Your lack of planning is not my emergency.”

Comment: Under a circumstance that people are willing to pay instantly for the services :D

Comment: There are currently 6 deleted answers (they happen to be the 6 last posted).

Comment: In `I've been stuck for weeks`, I don't read *speedy answer hugely more valuable than one a day or two from now*.

Comment: Yeah, let's all make people robots and eliminate any sense of personality in posts. I think it's ridiculous that "I'm tearing my hair out" falls under this "urgent" category. Meanwhile if you don't say that, people call you out for saying you didn't try enough. It's extremely frustrating being criticised for the way I've asked questions when I have honestly tried everything I know to solve an issue. I agree there shouldn't be a sense of urgency to question asking, but I don't think everything in that list presented above falls under that category.

Comment: @Barry: I understand your view. It is (only) my opinion that expressions of frustration can be lumped into other kinds of begging. However I think I can see the mistake you are making, and I say the following in order to try to help. Language does not mean what the speaker means, especially on the internet; language means what the hearer hears. Hearers should assume good intent, of course, but a compromise is required on both sides.

Comment: So, when someone insists that "Stack Overflow is my only hope" and "I am about to give up" and "I am tired and angry", we can assume those things are true for the speaker. But a portion of readers will see these as emotional blackmail - you have to help me otherwise my suffering will continue, and you are a bad person for not alleviating my stress and anxiety.

Comment: If we were to encourage those phrases, where do we stop? Is "help me otherwise I will lose my job" OK? We do get those too (see my old answer).

Comment: So I am quite sure all these phrases need to go. The poster is still able to get their help, and - critically - future readers can scan a pithy representation of the problem without any begging and waffle. That is, after all, the main point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PCM please do not change the format of the link at the bottom of the question. Is formatted that way so one copy paste the whole thing and have a working markdown link. A "clickable link" is worthless here, since you are already on the target page for that link.

Answer (score 713, accepted):

At best this is extra fluff in your question, which gets in the way of your actual question. **This makes it harder for people to help you, which makes it less likely that you'll get an answer.** Nobody is going to see that you need an answer ASAP and then drop everything they're doing in order to help you. Your emergencies are your own. Alternatively: lack of planning on your part does not constitute an emergency on my part.

At worst it'll be seen as very rude. **Specifically saying that your needs are urgent or that you need an answer ASAP implies that your time is more valuable than the time of other people asking questions, or of the people answering questions.** Other people asking questions want an answer just as much as you do. The people answering questions are doing this for free, in their spare time. Why is your time more valuable than theirs? This will actively discourage people from answering, and will probably even get you some downvotes, which makes it even less likely that you'll get an answer.

Also, in my experience, posts that contain "need help asap" and "urgent help plx" usually contain other problems. **Doing proper research takes time, so if you're in a hurry, you're probably not doing proper research.** Have you taken the time to do your own debugging? Have you taken the time to add print statements, or to narrow down the problem to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or to read the documentation? If you're in a hurry, then the answer is probably no. And if you haven't done these things, then it's harder for us to help you. **The best way to improve your chances of getting an answer is by making it easier for us to answer you.** Not including proper research makes it harder to help you, which again decreases your chances of getting an answer.

It might seem paradoxical, but **if you're in a hurry, the best thing you can do is slow down.**

So there's really no reason to include your urgency, and a bunch of reasons **not** to include it.

Comment: I realize that this is somewhat of and older post, but the MCVE statement is featured rather prominently. I feel it is necessary yet again to remind readers that only debugging questions require minimal reproducible examples. The object of a how-to question is to obtain an example, whereas the object of a debugging question is to solve the problem in the given example which is why an example is not only required, but is required to be both minimal and reproducible such that the problem can be easily reproduced with as little noise as possible.

Comment: I came across a link to this post just now, I always found that the best way to hurry things up is simply offering a bounty. Doesn't work every time, but it has its uses

Comment: @makoshichi But you have to wait at least day to offer a bounty, right?

Comment: @JuanMendes , Waiting a day is pointless imo. In this answer, theyre telling us to not to hurry, to wait, think, debug till it becomes minimal and on another thread (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251739/what-is-the-reason-behind-waiting-48-hours-to-offer-a-bounty) they're telling us to post the question asap so youll get the answer in time. This is a paradox I guess.

Comment: "if you're in a hurry, the best thing you can do is slow down." That's roughly what Doc Holliday said.

Comment: In the Army we learned Slow is smooth, smooth is fast.

Answer (score 264):

If the question has the same meaning without it then such content is noise and is unnecessary. It does not help anyone write an answer to the question. Feel free to remove it along with any other unnecessary text when editing such posts.

Comment: I've upvoted this as I agree with it. However I am looking for reasons as to _why_ it is noise, since I would like to be able to point people to this page as a canonical reference in the future.

Comment: it is noise because it **adds nothing** valuable to the question other than the person asking is impatient, which is irrelevant to everyone but the asker.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson makes a very valuable point. Also, as pointed out [in the accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/4433386) "need help ASAP", "urgent" remarks are often symptomatic of bad research. As such, taking the time to even type this would often be better spent describing your problem.

Comment: Also, I actively do that, and leave a comment when appropriate, something along the lines "I cleaned up the question, please concentrate on aspects important to people who might answer, not to yourself"; often, the reaction to these comments are positive, but there's also the red flag-raising "shut the hell up, if you don't answer my question, leave it alone", which luckily usually deters any potential answerers – improving the overall site in both question quality and tone.

Answer (score 165):

In my experience, these phrases do not actually improve the speed with which answers are posted, and they may in fact slow responses down. If someone posts an answer to an "urgent" question, then they were going to post it anyway.

I recently asked someone to desist from asking for ASAP treatment, and interestingly, they were genuinely surprised, and wondered if it was another arcane and unwritten guideline:

> I'm new to Stack Exchange I don't know why that is bad? I need help ASAP, is it bad to say so? I'm confused.

My response was that

> ... "ASAP" or "urgent" are, to a native English speaker, insistent demands that are attempts by a speaker to place someone under a sense of duty, or to transfer their own requirement of haste to someone else. It is generally thought as rude to force such obligations onto another person unless there is an exchange or agreement involved - so a manager might feel entitled to do this with an employee, for example. Since volunteers are here for their own leisure, they are unlikely to be motivated by any such attempts to jump to the front of the queue.

I had previously been of the opinion that an English speaker of moderate ability would be of the view that creating such pressure for volunteer helpers is socially unacceptable (and indeed I thought it would be the same for speakers of any language). However, given the above question posed to me, and the daily trickle of ASAP/urgent questions posted to the main site, I am minded to think that in some cultures this language is normal and not thought to be rude or excessively entitled at all.

Nevertheless, I think we should advise against it, since it will often be *understood* to be rude, leaving the OP to genuinely wonder why their post is getting a poor reception. It is worth noting that [elsewhere on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506), people have previously noted that if they see begging in a question, they will actively *not* answer it.

We should also make it plain that requests for speed are, in fact, an indication that a question should be regarded as more important than other questions already on the site. Whilst it is possible that a person's work genuinely *is* important - perhaps they work for a public health service, for example - we can have no way of knowing this, or policing it effectively. If we were to allow it, some people would unfairly claim all of their questions were urgent, and we would have no way of determining otherwise.

So, given that:

- these phrases do not make a discernible difference,
- a proportion of readers will regard them as a rudeness,
- some readers will skip to the next question or downvote,
- they are filler text not pertaining to the topic at hand,

I would take the view that readers should refrain from adding them. Furthermore, editors should remove them, as long as they are willing to fix up other items in a post at the same time.

I'd like to make a special mention of this question addition, which I have seen a few times recently:

> If I cannot fix this I will lose my job

Volunteer readers are, in general, sympathetic to people who have limited employment protections or who might genuinely be at risk of losing a client that is critical to their income. Nevertheless, this is one of the most emotionally manipulative phrases that can possibly be added: good people can easily be suckered into providing help that they themselves do not have time or energy for. It is an abuse of the kindness of people, and absolutely should not be added.

Comment: I already saw some people where "ASAP" and so on were common. This is typacally on management level by not so competent manager that like to use every english expression he knows in no-english mail. And so others that works with him end up with the same habit.

Comment: @Walfrat: I think that is true. I also have a suspicion that claiming to have an urgent piece of work is a happy, culturally-specific claim that the speaker has been entrusted with something important. So it becomes a small, pleasurable boast, and there is usually no intention to offend at all.

Comment: In this scenario, I would also remind askers who have sufficient reputation to [offer a bounty to "help attract more attention and more answers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). For new questions, not yet eligible for a bounty, I encourage askers to continue refining the question and providing progress updates. If the question can be improved, I also point them to the ["How to ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article in the Help Center. If the OP's question is truly urgent, they will also be responding to comments immediately which implies urgency.

Comment: @gfullam: I think that would be nice from the perspective of getting good questions. However it comes at the cost of accidentally teaching the user that begging phrases will be rewarded by bounties - which may not be good for editors' workloads.

Comment: @halfer I must have been unclear: I agree with you that begging phrases should be discouraged; my previous comment was merely a list of tactics I employ to encourage askers to get answers with urgency; all of which I borrowed from the Help Center. I am in full agreement with your conclusions here.

Comment: *I had previously been of the opinion that an English speaker of moderate ability would be of the view that creating such pressure for volunteer helpers is socially unacceptable (and indeed I thought it would be the same for speakers of any language).* I think the key here is that *cultures* vary in this regard, no matter the native language.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: I agree, although the phrases in contention _are_ in English, and so perhaps have nuances and connotations that gentler phrases in other languages might not carry. Whilst I want to be understanding of other cultural norms, the likelihood that most readers will think in an English way (i.e. that some phrases sound excessively demanding) perhaps needs to be borne in mind.

Comment: *these phrases do not actually make a difference to the speed* they certainly do, for me. I'm often occupying a few niche topics, and "I need help, my time is very valuable" questions *definitely* don't spur my initiative, and that might delay getting an answer indefinitely.

Comment: @gfullam I'm late to the table, but I think if the OP doesn't have enough rep to make a bounty, should we make the bounty for them? I read this as an occasionally nice gesture to convey that sometimes we do trust strangers on the internet? Since *our rep* represents the trust the community has in us, the fact that we use our own rep is similar to how we use our own credibility to endorse a new candidate to our HR

Comment: @Ooker: it's a nice gesture to do that, and the bounty system permits it. The only frustration for people who do that is when an OP - who may not care to become a member of the community - gets their help and doesn't ever return to thank the helpers or the bounty-adder.

Comment: @halfer for me, whether they comeback or not doesn't change the fact that they are helped. I'm fine with that. The problem is, they still need to be allowed to convey that they need help. This can be said in the comment, and should be untouched until someone help them. Then that comment can be deleted

Answer (score 68):

One reason I think these phrases are inappropriate, which I haven't seen raised yet: they are time-specific by their very nature, which works against Stack Overflow's function as an archive of knowledge. The question might have been urgent when it was asked, but it obviously won't be years later, even though the question and answer are still valuable.

We might decide that these phrases become fluff only after some amount of time (how much?) has passed, and that they should be removed after that, but that's just adding a maintenance burden we definitely don't need. Yuck. Better to leave them out altogether.

There's a difference between asking for a fast *answer* ("How can I solve this? Please help, urgent") and asking for a fast *solution* ("What's a quick way to solve this?"). Asking for a fast answer is fluff, but a fast solution can be valuable forever.

Answer (score 39):

> Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?

I can think of only a few:

- If you want your question downvoted and/or closed
- If you want snarky comments
- If you want your question largely ignored

Those are all times you'd want to put "urgent" or similar in the title. ;-)

If you actually want an answer to your question, there are no circumstances in which you want to put things like that in.

The premise of "...in order to obtain faster answers" is flawed. Putting "urgent" and such on a question will not get it answered more quickly.

It will, if anything, make it more likely that people who could help will skip over the question entirely, or take a jaundiced view of it and look for reasons to down- and/or close-vote it. Why? Because "urgent" and the like **usually** indicate a low-quality, did-no-research, did-no-critical-thinking question about a problem that's already been solved and for which an answer already exists on the site that the person posting the question just didn't bother to find because they're in a rush. By calling your problem "urgent," you lump it in with that rubbish, even if *your* question isn't rubbish.

That isn't universally true. It's just overwhelmingly the common case.

So all joking aside, the answer to "Under what circumstances" is: **"None"**.

Comment: I wish we could have this on an automatic pop-up every time someone writes **ASAP please!!!** in their post `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer: I'm really surprised the content filter allows "ASAP please", but as a quick search turned up a question from March 27th that still has it in (and not hidden in a code block or similar), well, I guess it does. :-)

Comment: I made a feature request to put an optional warning in the editing interface to discourage really bad phrases, but I haven't had any official bites on that yet. I may at some point do an expanded UI suggestion, to see if I can whip up some more interest.

Comment: "None" is too strong of a word. What if you need to reprogram a spaceship to hit a comet so that it changes its course and doesn't hit the Earth/Moon, but your code keeps spawning errors and the humanity has only several hours left to be saved? Just joking. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva: Easy: Don't post an SO question. Call Bruce Willis, who will say "Yippee-Ki-Ay" -- but, you know, sardonically -- while banging the computer on the side, and magically make it all work out. ;-)

Answer (score 27):

**Under no circumstance should you add any sort of phrasing along these lines to your question's title or body.**

Firstly, "urgency" is not a concept that Stack Overflow's Q&A model supports. On Stack Overflow, every question asked is expected to be a well-thought-out, high-quality seed for equally high-quality answers. There is no mechanism designed to advertise certain questions ahead of others; the bounty system can be used for this purpose, but is not intended for it.

Regardless of how urgent your question may appear to be to you, it is absolutely not urgent to the people who answer questions here. They are giving up their time, **for free**, and in return no expectations are placed on them for how quickly they answer questions (if at all).

Claiming your question is urgent implies that it is somehow more important than the other questions on this site, which is patently untrue. Such labelling on your behalf comes across as entitled and demanding, i.e. rude, which paradoxically means your question is less, not more, likely to be answered (quickly or not).

Many questions marked as "urgent" have historically turned out to be trivially solvable with a small amount of basic research. Therefore, many answerers instinctively avoid such questions as they are not worth answering except by a Google search.

Finally, since the only thing answerers here care about is the actual problem presented in your question, anything unrelated to the problem - such as claims of urgency - is seen as noise, and again is likely to lead to lower answer rates for your question.

In short, labelling your question as "urgent" is almost certain to **not** get you an answer sooner, and **is** almost certain to discourage people from answering it. **Don't do it.**

Comment: I just wonder how this answer adds any new point beside the ones given by other answers?