# Best way of getting a bounty on a post?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40912812/7080578) that I really could do with having an answer to ASAP, but I have only got 28 rep, so am unable to post a bounty.

This seems like the only way the question is gunna get any traffic, since it only has around 8 views currently, since yesterday.

Is there a way I can get a bounty put on it? Maybe a request bounty option? Is this something that is being looked at?

Comment: No, unless you can get someone with higher rep to add it for you. You probably shouldn't be using Stack Overflow for time-sensitive issues; there's no SLA or guarantee anyone will see or respond to your question... ever.

Comment: Honestly the best suggestion is to change your understanding of what Stack is for. I understand the need for an answer NOW, but that doesnt matter at all here. Anyway bounties tend to attract more answers towards the end of their lives, so this may not even fix your issue

Comment: In the case of this particular question, you might edit to (a) remove the inessential first paragraph (b) include samples of the before/after CSVs (c) include hex dumps of the before/after CSVs if they *appear* the same.

Comment: @Patrice I know it isn't the place for urgent answers, but I usually get good answers and within 36 hours when I do ask, so I thought it would be a good bet

Comment: @PaulRoub What do you mean by a hex dump?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump

Comment: I hope you get your answer before the rifleman comes.

Comment: @harambe oh of course. Most of the time this will be the case that your question gets a good answer quickly. However there is no guarantee for it, and if you don't get it, then tough luck :/.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to provide some good answers to questions, earning 5 upvotes and +50 reputation, so that you can place the bounty yourself. This would work with good *questions* as well, but you need 10 upvotes then.

As @Cerbrus notes, you can only place a bounty on a question which is at least 2 days old. But on the other hand, linking to this question on Meta will certainly generate additional views. Whether that is a good result, I don't know. Meta is unpredictable at times...

Also, in general, we don't like [urgent questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/4751173) here. I have yet to meet a question asker which doesn't want a speedy answer.

Comment: And even then, you can't apply one until 2 days have passed.