# An idea for a new help architecture on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

I have been doing some thinking:

I am a rookie developer, and I am learning the basics right now.

Stack Overflow has helped me immensely, and I appreciate both the presence of the site and of the community.

However I feel that the current structure of the site is a bit aggressive. Sometimes you really try your best, and then you might get stuck upon something that is really hard for you, but extremely obvious to others.

I have felt quite a lot of anxiety lately on whether I should ask a question or not. Sometimes this has been productive as it forced me to dig deeper before asking for help, but sometimes it gets plainly toxic.

For this I have been thinking that **there should be two kinds of questions** on Stack Overflow:

a) Permanent questions

*and*

b) "I am desperate for help questions" that will self destruct after 48 hours.

In order to put some limits upon help-vampires, each user should be able to ask only three desperate questions a month AND in order to not pollute the amazing educational legacy of the site, these posts will self-destruct after 48 hours.

Points gained by these questions and answers should be kept on a different reputation board, and for every 50 points earned through asking "desperate questions" you could be gaining 5 regular reputation points. Answering desperate questions however should give you half the amount of regular reputation points.

**I think that this kind of division, is truly needed in order to keep people happier and limit question pollution without stiffling the efficient diffusion of knowledge.**

New users should think before they ask but they should also have a credible way to show how engaged they are.

I believe that this kind of structure I propose will be hugely beneficial for the site (cause it will rekindle active interest) while also limiting noise pollution.

What the community thinks?

Comment: Wait! Isn't your self-destructed posts a kind of chat?

Comment: We already have self-destructing questions. The difference is that they leave a residue of sorrow and question bans.

Comment: This will invariably end up with the good answerers avoiding the 'temporary question' queue and then we will have an echo chamber of poor questions and answers. There are plenty of Q&A sites which will allow sub-par quality questions. There's nothing preventing people from asking on those sites when they're desperate and can't write a good quality question. You get what you pay for, though. SO is successful specifically *because* these kinds of questions are removed.

Comment: @Rob:  It's not always beginners who ask for immediate help.

Comment: @Makoto I couldn't find a better duplicate - however the answers to that question apply to this (and also to that question's dupe target).

Comment: If an answer is incredibly obvious, then you haven't done enough research or you haven't used a good tutorial. If the questions are low quality or being closed, then learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). High-quality questions about basic topics can exist, but most have already been asked before.

Comment: Mentoring new programmers who don't know yet how to do research is a noble task. It's not what Stack Overflow was designed to do, though - that's what courses, classes at school and University, individual mentoring situations, internships, etc. are for.

Comment: @Kadriles no. a chat question has a very limited audience.

Comment: @RobertColumbia do you know that you cannot delete your own question even if it has attracted negative votes, if it has upvoted answers? what kind of self-destruction is that?

Comment: @Rob I honestly dont understand if you bothered to read the question: how can you have an echo chamber when these questions will self destruct?

Comment: @Makoto Obviously beginners are in more need for help and they are feeling more overwhelmed from entering a deep subject. Do you think is strange that they ask more questions?

Comment: @4castle what can be truly obvious to me may be a mystery to you.

Comment: @Pekka웃 so you dont think that a site may evolve further than its initial design.

Comment: Oh, it certainly *may*. But this site doesn't *want* to.

Comment: what does not change is cursed to become obsolete

Comment: @alexandros84: I've never had an issue with beginners asking questions.  In contrast, they should also expect that we're not here to answer *every* question they have, and we're not beholden to their deadlines in the slightest.

Comment: `what does not change is cursed to become obsolete` lol, it'll be a while until Stack Overflow will be obsolete. Mentoring is a fundamentally different mission from what SO/SE is doing right now. What is the case for SO fundamentally changing its mission?

Comment: sure lol. once myspace has been a king and now is in the garbage.

Comment: I don't think you have really understood what this community is about. For the people who participate here it's  never been about being the biggest, most dominant resource, the next Facebook or Myspace or Google. One important element is *building a lasting library of programming questions and answers that future generations can reuse*. That's the main reason for many people why they donate their time here - because when helping the asker you're helping future visitors with the same problem, too. Mentoring is by design much more custom-tailored, and less useful to people other than the mentee.

Comment: @Makoto you are a free person: if you dont have time to help someone else dont. I feel that others might feel differently. I dont get it why this should be "a we vs. you" matter.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think is you that you are detached with the issue of how difficult it is for a beginner to grow in an over-saturated environment like SO. and precisely because I respect and I get the vision that you describe I spoke about self-destructing questions who wont leave a permanent footprint on the site.

Comment: @alexandros "difficult for a beginner to grow"? In 2017, with millions of tutorials, books, and Q&A sites available online? I learned programming when there was no Internet. Only books and maybe a couple bulletin boards I was allowed to use an hour a day using a dial-up modem. *That's* "difficult to grow."

Comment: (I do get what you mean, though - it's still a world that is very very hard to navigate for newbies. That's something that may need addressing - but maybe not by Stack Overflow. The model would have to be so much different than this Q&A online RPG based around imaginary points...)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, and you had far less competition. I just dont get why this has to be a black or white issue.

Comment: `I just dont get why this has to be a black or white issue` Well, in practice, it's not quite black and white - we *do* a lot of mentoring and helping folks out. It happens all the time in comments, when an answer is not immediately obvious to someone. I guess the main argument against becoming "softer" by allowing "please help" type questions has been that it would lead to a giant swamp of questions that don't have value for future visitors, and wouldn't be very attractive to answer. After all, there's very little we can stop lazy people from creating new account after new account....

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for understanding. The toxicity on newbies is terrible. Do you know that after this post someone went to my original profile and downvoted my second ever question in here? How toxic and little is that? It was only my second question!

Comment: @alexandros84 you have absolutely NO proof that it is what happened. Not saying it's impossible it is what happened, but it's also possible someone saw your question and downvoted it organically. Remember that any post here is for the next user with the same issue to see and find. This is also why the proposal of questions that auto-delete is rejected so harshly. It goes against the mission of Stack : build a permanent repo of knowledge.

Comment: @Patrice I have taken my profile on SO seriously. I have asked three questions over three months and I have learned a lot about the ethos of the site from the answers I got. That question suddenly got downvoted overnight after months of being inert. This is toxic and sadistic. Plainly and true.

Comment: And was downvoted again! Just now. Haha some people simply cant handle a disagreement!

Comment: @alexandros84 Again, I am not saying you are wrong. Just saying that you MIGHT be wrong, and the site is actually supposed to be LIKE that. Your questions are expected to be viewed and get voted on once in a while. It is possible someone went in and threw a downvote. It's also possible someone organically searched on Google, found your question, went "not helpful to me, I am downvoting". There is such a thing as the "meta effect" that tends to happen however where going on meta tends to cast a bigger spotlight on your content.

Comment: In any case, since you cannot be sure, getting riled up against it is a bit counter-productive :/.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't any substantial difference between a user's question, whether or not they need an answer now or can research an answer and get one later.

To be blunt, questions which warrant or ask for "immediate" attention indicate that their time is more valuable than ours; even though we may be knowledgeable, we have lives and other obligations outside of Stack Overflow, too.

[There has been discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/1079354) on this matter in the past, but I want to address your specific request here.

> a) permanent questions
>
> and
>
> b) "I am desperate for help questions" that will self destruct after
>   48 hours.

What is the fundamental difference between A and B if I see B at 47 hours 59 minutes and 00 seconds of its lifetime?  Should I be deprived of the answer (if any exists) just because the OP needed to get something done on a deadline?  What of the students who can take full advantage of a scheme like this to cover up any evidence of their plagiarism?  Or worse, what of the actual "professionals" who make use of Stack Overflow as if it were an outsourcing platform to get somework done on the sly?  Those thoughts **alone** dissuade me from a feature like this.

I suppose the root of your suggestion comes from this:

> I have felt quite a lot of anxiety lately on whether I should ask a question or not. Sometimes this has been productive as it forced me to dig deeper before asking for help, but sometimes it gets plainly toxic.

Stack Overflow has a lot of answers on it, and a ton of questions.  A handful of those questions are actually decent.  The vast majority *aren't*.  The community-at-large is vigilant in making sure that the questions which don't belong aren't kept around, and it's natural to have concerns that your question may fall into that category.  [Have a read at this question/answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1079354); the answer is somewhat satirical but it still rings true; if you do your research, *and* you show that you've done your research, your question will be well-received.

Comment: "To be blunt, questions which warrant or ask for "immediate" attention indicate that their time is more valuable than ours; even though we may be knowledgeable, we have lives and other obligations outside of Stack Overflow, too." Nobody is forcing you to answer a question.

Comment: @alexandros84: The only way that kind of system could ever possibly work is if users were otherwise obligated to pay attention to "urgent" questions.

Comment: Honestly I think you are judging out of your own feelings. People at the beginning did not even believe that wikipedia would be successful... but it was. I do get what you say however.

Comment: @alexandros84 and in that time thousands of sites were thought to be the next big thing and went bankrupt. If you think your idea is so revolutionary and the way forward; go build it.