# What should be done with questions from people who are currently taking a test in school?

Tags: discussion

I think there's probably already a question/answer that covers this, but I had a search and couldn't find anything directly relevant.

There's the classic [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823) but this is different IMO as helping someone currently taking a test would be viewed as cheating by most test setters.

Here's an example opening line from a question:

> Please help me ASAP, I'm currently in an exam. The question has some existing code and we have to modify it. It's to do with [some topic], please help me.

It seems fairly clear cut to me that this question should be closed.

Am I right about that? If so what should I be choosing as the close reason?

Close -> Off-Topic -> Other, with a comment of "Asking for help to cheat during live test at school"?

Comment: Judge it like any other question. It's not our job to prevent students from cheating, it's the job of the school they attend.

Comment: @ivarni Thanks for the PoV, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: see also: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/839601)

Comment: @gnat That first link seems especially relevant, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're not here to help people "ASAP", but other than that I have no objections against this. When these people enter the job market, they'll likely use Stack Overflow. So why prevent them from consulting it during an exam? If they get an answer, they hopefully have learned something from it, and we hopefully have created a new useful resource on the internet. Sounds great to me!

And like @ivarni says, it's not our job to prevent cheating. For all you know, they may even be allowed to consult Stack Overflow during the exam.

Comment: I agree. If people want to rely on Stack Overflow to be able to solve the tasks in their exams and do not want to learn the stuff up front, then sure, let them ask a question and hope for the best. If the question is good, yay, if it isn’t (which is likely if we’re being honest), then there surely is a close reason anyway.

Comment: @poke yes. Searching SO, either directly or via Google, is a useful tool that shoud be available. As for actually copypasta exam questions, well, yes, they are very likely to be bad, in that they often set tasks whose only purpose is to test comprehension and are pretty well useless for anything else, and totally useless for future SO visitors/users, eg 'Bubble sort a linked-list', (yech...).  They usually get closed pretty quick.

Comment: [I was once allowed to *answer* questions during a test.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended#comment6186106_5455770)

Comment: There is a difference between preventing and encouraging though. SO encourages people just to copy and paste without thinking. There should probably be a rule against posting anything over 50 lines of code if it's clearly some kind of test or at least make it an option to flag posts for people assigning the tests and not having to play a constant game of cat and mouse.

Comment: *"When these people enter the job market, they'll likely use Stack Overflow. So why prevent them from consulting it during an exam?"* Because exams are not meant to mimic real life situations. They are meant to test some specified set of capabilities. The capabilities tested by an exam are specified by educators. You may think it is illegitimate for educators to test capabilities that you think will not be required in the workplace, but (1) the purpose of education is far more than just to prepare students for a workplace, and (2) do you object so strongly to educators deciding to examine ...

Comment: ... their students in a way which does not mimic a real life situation, that you would protest against them doing so by trying to change their exam into more of a real life situation? (3) Are you *sure* that programmers in the workplace will never find themselves with a problem that they aren't able to find a solution on Stack Overflow? Such problems are generally more difficult than exam problems for beginner programmers, but the capability of solving a problem *for yourself* is absolutely something that professional programmers need, so it's not even unrealistic for an exam to simulate this.

Answer (score 6):

From a SO point of view you should get rid of all the exam-context that's cluttering the question and then judge what is left whether it is a valid question for this site and act accordingly.

Concerning the ethical reservations about cheating, I would probably wait some hours before posting an answer so it is most likely useless for the exam.

Answer (score 6):

It should also be noted that using SO during an exam isn't necessarily cheating.

In the class my sisters taking, they're actually encouraged to use SO during exams; both to ask questions and browse existing ones. She's taking a Stats course that uses R, and the course is geared toward non-programmers. There's a heavier emphasis on using the tools available to you to solve a problem, instead of forcing memorization.

Unless someone outright admits to actively cheating (which I *have* seen), it's not feasible for us to accurately judge if someone's cheating or not.

Comment: Exam setting and rules depend on the school and (in some cases) teachers... SO cant be expected to keep track of them

Comment: @SurajRao Yeah, I hadn't considered that the rules could vary so much, it's something I'll try to do in the future. ivarni's suggestion of ignoring that part and focusing on the quality of the question itself was very useful to me.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was agreeing with you :)

Comment: 'the course is geared toward non-programmers' - SO is geared toward non-non-programmers.

Comment: @MartinJames That's besides the point though if they're capable of formulating an appropriate, ontopic question. The course is geared towards non-programmers, but they have to learn the basics of programming. The questions she's asked me are far above the typical breed of crap that we see on SO on a daily basis.

Comment: @Carcigenicate 'far above the typical breed of crap that we see on SO' well, even that is a very low bar, but if they are good questions, fine:)

Comment: @MartinJames Ya, I guess that doesn't say much. My point was the quality of the questions matters more than the background of the asker. If someone has read how to use the site, and is able to make valuable contributions, the fact that they started the course as a non-programmer shouldn't be important.  Of course being a non-programmer puts you at a disadvantage, but it shouldn't rule you out entirely.