# Should I simply edit out "urgent" from questions?

Tags: discussion

Should I just edit out all references to urgency from a question, or are questions indicating urgency inherently bad?

It's not uncommon to see questions with "URGENT!!1!" in a the title or body. Should I just edit these parts out, leaving the rest of the question alone if it's otherwise good?

I recently made an edit where I removed "- urgent" from a title, with the edit reason "Removed 'urgent' for the sake of the OP". Should I have included more context with that edit decision? Was just removing the references to urgency a good idea?

Comment: I think so. For the sake of SO, declaring urgency is just noise. It strikes me as similar to erasing a "Thanks in advance". It never added any value to the question in the first place.

Comment: Yes, get rid of it.  I don't know why they do it, it just generates downvotes and the rest of the question gets ignored:(  It's actually borderline rude/abusive, but I don't bother flagging such stuff.

Comment: Remove it when you run into it, fix other problems as well.  Please don't edit *every* question, it only matters on the Q+A that is helpful and worth re-activating again.

Comment: You could add a comment referencing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)
A: *In short: Never.* – TylerH Jun 21 '16 at 15:28

**Yes**, you're fine always removing "urgent" from titles and question bodies; [halfer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) and I did it quite often: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/845830/urgent-edits

Regarding if those questions are inherently bad, I would answer: **no**. The urgency wording is simply fluff that should be removed. Judging if the question is bad should be done regardless of what fluff it had previously. So if the question actually matches one of the predefined close reasons, then vote to close as well, otherwise leave it open.

Comment: Yes to this. Often questions that are marked as urgent/ASAP are poor anyway, but this week I found one where begging had been added to a relatively good question. I was evidently in a good mood, since I upvoted it, even if I also thought the question author was overly entitled and did not really merit the vote.