# Can I ask about possible errors in my code or for a "review"?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I am currently developing an application in Rust that uses a protocol in which I am quite new. And I would like someone to tell me if my code is good or what it can improve, or if I'm doing something wrong.

What I did before I came here and asked this question was I asked my question in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280570/can-i-use-this-way-to-start-fastcgi-request-always), and it didn't get enough attention and I don't think it will. So, IN CASE my question is still unanswered, can I ask the same question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: There is [no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) on Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Have some patience. It has only been 4 days since you posted the question on Code Review. And, if it doesn't get answered on one SE site, **do not post it on another site**. Each site is for a different purpose, so the question would likely be off-topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, I'm afraid that the question that you describe would be off-topic for this site as this is not a code-review site nor is it a forum or discussion site.

Specifically:

> I would like someone to tell me if my code is good or what it can improve, or if I'm doing something wrong.

This sort of request is very broad and more of a code-review type question, suggesting that it would not be a good fit for this site.

> What I did before I came here and asked this question was I asked my question in code review, and it didn't get enough attention and I don't think it will.

How long did you wait? That site is not as high traffic as this one, but like this one, proper tagging, writing a clear, appropriate, informative and attention-grabbing title, and writing a well-crafted question, one that piques the interest of the site users can make a *huge* difference in how much positive attention your question receives. Also, like this site, that site would expect a very focused question. Also, putting a bonus on your question can make a huge difference, if you have adequate rep on that site to be able to do this.

> So, IN CASE my question is still unanswered, can I ask the same question on stackoverflow?

No, this site cannot and should not be used as an overflow site for questions that are poorly received on any other Stack Exchange site.

Have you gone through the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) link, and more specifically, have you reviewed their [ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) link to see how to best use that site? If not, I suggest that would be a great place to start.