# Why is SO discouraging questions and answers writing?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, downvotes, moderation

I have been continuously feeling that SO nowadays discourages Q&A writing on SO.

I come across a problem, and I do:
- Search (Google, Bing, etc.)
- Find similar a question and answers that links to some SO old question and answers
- Then I read this Q&A, take the answers.
- But, often
- the given answers don't apply directly
- are incomplete or not properly explain
- don't address a little different use case

I develop my own solutions to my problem, and whenever it seems appropriate, I post the solution to the SO as a new question and answer. I tend to
- provide details (concise, but with more information with less verbosity).
- Provides input, output, and screenshots
- Provide an explanation of a little different use case.

I do all this, so it is helpful to me and also to others, and it is documented on SO whenever I come across a similar problem. A code on my hard drive gets lost some way and is too difficult to find after a few years.

It takes me another 2-3 hours to put a good solution together. But SO continuously discourages me by downvoting the questions immediately, closing the question in a few hours.
Downvoting the answers in a few hours.

These SO bots or gatekeepers think I am here to increase my reputation and write banal answers. I have a better way of spending my time.

Just take a look at this post:

[Resize images in python using openCV and PIL by padding, by saving resolution on both height and width, and to a fixed resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75817727/resize-images-in-python-using-opencv-and-pil-by-padding-by-saving-resolution-on)

This post answered the question with needed details, clarity, and examples. It's based on other question and answers, but I had to read through them, work (write the code) on it myself, clean it out, test it, and put it there on SO.

It got downvotes in less than an hour, even though I posted it with an answer. And it's not the first time it happened.

SO really is going to be replaced with ChatGPT. There are not enough people writing answers, and all it's doing is discouraging those who are putting in honest efforts.

Why is SO discouraging questions and answers writing?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. You just posted requirements.

Comment: The question you've linked to isn't asking a question; it just provides a list of requirements. When you are going to post a question with the intention of answering it yourself you still need to ensure that question meets all the guidelines of the site.

Comment: See [ask] - self-answering is great, but you still _have_ to write a question that meets Stack's guidelines. Yours doesn't.

Comment: "*NOTE: Please do not downvote. I am writing an answer to this*" is a good reason for a downvote. Posts should not contain such notes.

Comment: If you want to share knowledge, your answers should explain how to do it, not just share a solution. Answers without a proper explanation may be downvoted.

Comment: @Dharman
Well if I didnot put that note, it will have more downvotes. I was going to remove that in an hour or so. But, gatekeepers here are busy looking on the coming side of the gate. There is so much garbage in old answers, some are even wrong and have high votes. It would be better if those answers were cleaned, downvoted and responded to.

Comment: *"SO really is going to be replaced with ChatGPT"* *Very* unlikely, ChatGPT is not a replacement for experienced, knowledgable people. People that do choose to use ChatGPT instead of sites like [so] are going to run in to problems much sooner than that think, as they slowing implement more of its convincing, but *very* **wrong**, suggestions.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine
Well, I should start writing in a new language then, not English I guess.

Comment: Sure old answers need to be looked at but everyone is busy dealing with new low quality posts.

Comment: @ThomA
Nothing replaces something at 100%, but just reducing the traffic by 80% to 90% is enough so say it's replaced. 
I don't look SO any more to setup a user more, or create a pandas dataframe. Too easy with GPT, and helps me focus on the real problem.
I wrote a solution that GPT could not answer very correctly, an posted on SO, only to be disappointed and discouraged. Tell me who SO is going to sustain itself if the knowledge that is niche specific and requires human intervention gets discouraged?

Comment: If ChatGPT could replace stack overflow, why would that be bad? At the moment it can't so nothing to worry about.

Comment: Must read for self-answered questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting

Comment: @Dharman
that was not a low-quality post. 
Gatekeepers have 5 secs to decide if a post is good or bad. That's what is driving this.

Comment: *" I wrote a solution that GPT could not answer very correctly, an posted on SO, only to be disappointed and discouraged."* But you didn't write a question; it wasn't the answer that was downvoted, it was your non-question. The *answer* you wrote doesn't have *any* votes against it. No one has discouraged you to not provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, it is. I just explained it to you.

Comment: I'd be very happy if ChatGPT could replace stack overflow. It will be great and I cannot wait.

Comment: Who are these gatekeepers?

Comment: Confusingly, at the time this post was made, it appears that your question had a score of 0; with 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes. I'm not sure why that is "discouraging". It was closed, sure, but the reason for that is in the closure reason; the correct response to that is to edit the post to address the closure reason.

Comment: I'm worried for SO too - there are already plenty of "ChatGPT providied me this code but it does not work" with likely more coming - I agree with @everestial007 that it is a problem for SO and unlikely get better with time.

Comment: Votes on Meta are different, @everestial007 ; they often denote a user's agreement (or disagreement) with the post. The downvotes are more likely that people disagree with what you are stating. Though, it could also be that the "question" suffers the same problem the link post does: it doesn't ask a question. It's at best a rant.

Comment: @everestial007 you may want to re-read tooltip for downvote "this question does not show any research effort" (self-answered has its own tag on meta and plenty of guidance) in addition to "disagree" votes.

Comment: It's not that this question is unclear, it's that we don't find it very useful. People on meta also downvote when they disagree with the premise.

Comment: The downvotes are likely because people strongly disagree with your stance and find your reaction to the poor reception of a low quality question exaggerated and not useful.

Comment: @Dharman
Tell me how is the answer that is curated, tested, provided a very good example with and concise details but less verbosity - not helpful???
I built my knowledge based on SO and was only adding to it. But, it's understood other wise.

Comment: @everestial007: Stop, ___read___, and ___listen___. You've been told ___several___ times already that the example question you listed is _not a good question_! A list of requirements is ___unacceptable___ as a SO question. ___That___ is why it got downvoted and closed. It has nothing to do with domain knowledge or people being unable to read English. Your question is simply in ___blatant___ violation of SO's asking criteria. Stop blaming everyone else. ___Your___ question is inadequate and that is a problem ___you___ can (and should) solve.

Comment: As an answer on this post says, they don't discourage good answers and questions. However, it is **VERY** hard to write questions. It's very easy to get downvoted for small mistakes. I would recommend getting knowledgeable about a topic before asking a question or answering a question. Also, note that making too many mistakes in writing questions can lead to a question ban (like what I received a while before). Good luck!

Comment: Pro-tip: despite appearances, it’s still possible to post a question here without the prophesy that ChatGPT is going to take over the world and make all of us redundant. Give it a try next time, you might find the number of eyes rolling at your post reducing somewhat.

Comment: “SO really is going to be replaced with ChatGPT. There are not enough people writing answers, and all it's doing is discouraging those who are putting in honest efforts.” - Perhaps in a decade. ChatGPT today is useless. It absolutely cannot generate a coherent accurate answer to a programming question unless the individual training ChatGPT, has to be able to literally write the code themselves to get a coherent code that isn’t absolute horrible. ChatGPT content is utter garbage. It’s banned for a reason and it’s definitely not because it generates coherent answers.

Comment: It absolutely is possible to write good, self-answered questions that get positive attention. Here are some examples out of my own history: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631401; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078605; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666408 (I'm planning to revise that last one to remove content about `while` loops, that will be covered by a companion question about "imperative" iteration).

Comment: "Gatekeepers have 5 secs to decide if a post is good or bad. That's what is driving this." Only because of the risk that otherwise someone will attempt an answer to a bad question. There is [no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/) on Stack Overflow generally, and a self-answer definitely forestalls "fastest gun in the west" answers. However, it only **takes** a few seconds to see that your question was bad.

Comment: [Cross posted to MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387837/why-is-so-discouraging-questions-and-answers-writing) (though recommended in a comment (at MSE)).

Comment: I do the same. I use the site as a sort of public documentation repository. I try to ignore rep and just post solutions to problems that I couldn't find the solution for online. Very rarely to ask and immediately answer a question if the question was not even asked. Using the site to **ask for help** might as well be impossible and is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 33):

Stack Overflow does not discourage good questions and answers. It's the whole reason this site exists. You are the only one who can discourage yourself. You set yourself bad expectations, take votes too personally, and don't follow the recommendations from the community.

Stack Overflow encourages participation by giving out unicorn points and badges for well-formulated on-topic questions, and clear, thoroughly explained answers. Posts that community finds useful are upvoted and the author gains reputation points.

We are happy for you to share knowledge with the rest of us. We welcome experienced developers willing to share their knowledge and improve the programming community. **One of the best things you can do is ask a question that someone could find themselves asking and answer it yourself.** The question needs to be clearly written and on-topic. The answer needs to be properly explained, with some code examples when applicable.

In your case, the question is just a list of requirements. It has a too long title. It's vague and too broad. In revision 1 it also contained some unnecessary meta-commentary. All of this is a reason why your readers don't find it useful. The question cannot really be answered without writing a full application, which is the reason it is closed.

The answer also contained meta-commentary but it did not have any explanation. It's just code dump. What are you trying to teach us? Please explain how it works and how to achieve the thing you described.

Comment: Then why is this question (here, in this stackoverflow meta stack) downvoted?

Comment: @everestial007 Because votes work differently on meta: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Because it's a long list of excuses and misconceptions about how your question is good and shouldn't be downvoted, accusations of _"SO bots or gatekeepers"_, and lastly some _"ChatGPT"_ nonsense... That'll attract downvotes, @everestial007.

Comment: ChatGPT generated content is a big flaming piece garbage. I would rather be forced to use Quora than read another ChatGPT generated answer

Comment: Standard "SO is toxic" echo-chambering... Who's being toxic here? You ___aren't___ listening. You're dismissing _any_ advice and you're disregarding _any_ opinion other than your own. You've already made up your mind about SO... You're not here for advice or a discussion, you're here to rant. Now _that_ is toxic.

Comment: @everestial007 One platform complaining about another platform, how surprising. You can find the same outcry about reddit https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Reddit-such-a-toxic-place and then you could look-up "why is quora toxic" and continue this useless journey.

Comment: Instead of looking those things up, ask ChatGPT instead. Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: If you wrote *code* that completes a small **task**, the appropriate way to share it with the world is to put it on a public code repository site such as GitHub, make a proper installable package/application out of it (as applicable) and include documentation that explains what problem it solves. Stack Overflow is for sharing *knowledge* about a small *problem*. If you have a list of things that need to happen when the code runs, you have a task, not a problem.

Comment: ChatGPT *can* be a useful tool, but it is a very sharp tool. Use the tool incorrectly and the result can be catastrophic. Each and every piece of information it provides must be vetted thoroughly. For instance, use it for generating ideas for solving a problem. But be aware the advice may be very bad; it wants to please you, not provide correct information. The "chat" part is fitting.