# Community for tech news

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow is a great platform for collaborative editing, every adequate question gets answered and the community cares about the quality a lot.

Could Stack Overflow additionally become a unique platform for news brought by the community?

Question part can contain the main news post, answers may bring more details or a completely different point of view. Editing the post becomes the main tool to make **ideal proof-rich objective content**. Posting and editing can be made by members with experience proven by points they got in the community related to the topic.

Comment: A quite important part of SO is that quality may need time grow. For example, posts may need several edits to be perfect. This wouldn't work in the news sector where a lot of stuff is about speed, not about quality or accuracy. By the time a news post has been fixed it may not be interesting anymore or outdated and thus time got wasted there.

Comment: News get updates by the authors on every platform in our days. Tech news do not become outdated very fast. Imho SO has power to make news better

Comment: A Q&A format doesn't really seem suitable for news, also Stack Overflow's format isn't really suitable for discussion, which is one of the points you seem to be getting at by answers bringing a different point of view.

Comment: I mean, in theory, this is what the blog was described as being intended to be. though... i'd argue it has failed at this aspect.

Comment: Also a point you don't really touch upon is moderation. Who will validate and ensure people don't use it for fake news? Such a platform also seems like it would be easy to abuse for spamming purposes (As long as it is disguised well). Who will moderate those?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I see your point. Tech articles might work better than news. I still think news is a considerable candidate though because SO pattern is very performant in terms of providing good objective and neutral content, and it'd be still worth to try to apply it.

Comment: Moderation can be made by people who are distinguished from the rest by proficiency proven via points which they got in the community related to topic of the article.

Comment: What does "ideal proof-rich objective content" mean, and why is it a goal? Q&A isn't objective, so I don't see how SO would have any claim to objectivity. I'd vote for professional journalists to be researching and writing tech news (not that they're objective, necessarily, but they do (in theory) have standards of journalistic conduct that an average SO user wouldn't). I don't see why SO shouldn't just stick to the one thing it does best: professional and enthusiast programming Q&A, rather than water it down with extras like "collectives", teams, articles, blogs and news.

Comment: @ggorlen you forgot to mention "documentation" - which is probably closest to "news" and tried to be very close to what OP seem to envision - interesting information no one particularly needs... (except news is even farther away from SO's goal to create lasting content - news are by design 12-48hours lifetime)

Comment: *[Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation)* reference (capital "D").

Answer (score 13):

### Absolutely not.

As a preamble: it's one thing to ask whether a community's existing norms, format etc. can be adapted to fit some specific new thing. It's quite another to propose that a site become something fundamentally different. Clearly it would not be well received to, say, go to Wikipedia and ask why not add upvotes and downvotes to articles and sections thereof. So I will consider the proposal purely in the framework of how it fails to align with the site's existing purpose.

First, most tech news isn't even about technologies; it's about the companies. That's blatantly off topic here. Even if there is some new technology, to be on topic it would have to be something related to programming, that developers can use (for example, a new or changed API).

Second, business news, especially tech news, is rife with self-promotion, running the gamut from astroturfing to outright spam. There is no good reason to invite any of that in, even if we trust the community to write their own content objectively.

Third, this is **not a discussion forum**. Answers need to be *answering a concrete question*. They are not for "points of view" at all (that's fundamentally opposed to "objective content"!); while answers might recommend "best practices" for working with some API, they're not for the purpose of, say, coming up with uses for it. They're also not for "bringing more details" - that isn't a way that one can engage with a *question*. A proposed question that is lacking in detail should be closed - there are literally two separate closure reasons specifically for that purpose.

Finally (and related to the previous point), Stack Overflow's attitude towards timing is fundamentally incompatible with "news". There is [no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) here, and the goal is to create a *library* - i.e., *lasting* reference information. We can hardly even manage to shuffle old, outdated, highly-upvoted answers out of the way - how could we hope to deal with topics that are only meant to last for a few days? If we allowed ourselves to focus on the "news cycle", that would pull even more scarce attention away from doing the thing that is *actually* the purpose of the site.

If a new technology comes out that is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and you can think of an on-topic [question](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) about that technology that [suits the existing format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ([whether you can answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or not), and you are [not trying to advertise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) - then, by all means, go ahead.