# Is there a good way to intentionally ask a duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

This question [How to check if an image is a scaled version of another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422278/how-to-check-if-an-image-is-a-scaled-version-of-another-image) was asked in 2010 and the accepted answer is from 2013. I think that in the last 10 years, there might be different and potentially better answers to this question.

How can I ask it again without getting closed as a duplicate?

Comment: You could add a bounty to the question

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there might be different and better solutions to this *outside* of it's age?

Comment: @KevinB Because sites like tineye and google image search can take an input image and find similar (or the same image, scaled), quickly, I speculate that they might have more sophisticated techniques to do this. (or they're just doing the same thing very fast on a large dataset, who knows)

Comment: so, nothing specific to c# then? just a hunch because some online web tools are fast?

Comment: that's correct. the code provided, while in C#, looks like a general algorithm you could implement in other languages

Comment: "*I think that in the last 10 years, there might be different and potentially better answers to this question*" If there are then someone would have already posted them on that question.

Comment: Extract features and find similar images is an entirely different task than find the exact same image, scaled, and comes with an entirely different set of algorithms (e.g. SIFT). For the first, you can reduce images to a small consistently sized feature space, which makes search efficient, for the second, that's not an option.

Comment: It is worth noting, relevant to the dates for this particular question, that [TinEye has existed since 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinEye).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a good way to intentionally ask a duplicate question?

**No.**<sup>1</sup>

> How can I ask it again without getting closed as a duplicate?

Do not attempt this. Instead,

> I think that in the last 10 years, there might be different and potentially better answers to this question.

Since *the task description, and therefore the question, has not fundamentally changed*, any "different and potentially better answer" **belongs in the same place**.

That's why we don't automatically close old questions: so that they can continue to receive better, newer, up-to-date answers indefinitely, in the cases where that makes sense. There is [no sense of urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) here.

If you like, you may instead draw attention to the question [by placing a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Better yet, if you *find* a superior answer through your own research, then add it to the question! This way, everyone wins.

<sub><sup>1</sup>At least, not unless there are *already many* duplicates of the question, and they're *all bad*, and you can write a better one to make *everything else* be a duplicate of *that*. But this task is better left to someone who has a gold badge in a relevant tag, who can then close those duplicates unilaterally. This is a massive undertaking and it should be discussed with the community first if at all possible.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Let's apply some simple logic. When it comes to Google image search I would find it highly doubtful that nobody else would be interested in how it works; without even looking I simply know that there is a lot of information out there. But I did go look, of course Stack Overflow was the first hit: [How is google search by image implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822455/how-is-google-search-by-image-implemented) .

Point is that there is no reason to ask a duplicate question because you have all you need to be more specific at your disposal. Knowing an existing service which does what you want is pure gold as that is such an easy search term to plop into your favourite search engine.